# jQuery toggle by ESC and clicking

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have this simple script

```
$(".showHide").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    jQuery(this).children('.showHide').toggle();
});
```

I don't know how to 
1) Hide .modal if is ESC presed
2) Hide .modal if user click outside of .modal-inside

https://jsfiddle.net/zkx9gt2u/1/

Comment: What do you want ,what is ESC  ?

Comment: bind your esc key so that when its pressed, a javascrip is called. look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578630/close-lightbox-when-esc-is-pressed

Comment: bind a click function just like you have one above to the document which is outside your div to remove the modal.

Comment: You could use a bootstrap modal

Comment: what is this link in the end supposed to be? it shows nothing meaningful to me/does not work. please write what one is supposed to find there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$(".showHide").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".showHide").children('.showHide').toggle();
});

$(".modal-inside").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
        if (e.which == 27) {
            $(".showHide").children('.showHide').hide();
        }
    });
```

## Edit

I recently came across bootstrap modal which got added in v3. It does exactly what you want. A good starting point would be [official site](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and  [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-modals/).

E.g. if you wish to close your modal using esc key, all you have to do is this:

```
var options = {
    "backdrop" : "static"
}

$('#id-of-modal').modal(options);
```

Comment: if you have difficulty understanding the code, just let me know, i will put some comments